# Migrate asp.net site to windows azure and Error 102 WAT080

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I try to migrate asp site to windows azure.I follow this following link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zkap/archive/2012/07/29/how-to-migrate-an-existing-asp-net-website-to-windows-azure.aspx

After follow the the step and try to debug I got following error:

```
Error   102 WAT080 : Failed to locate the Windows Azure SDK. Please make sure the Windows Azure SDK v1.7 is installed.
```

I search and found [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28045).I try to download and install but I got  a error:

```
The installation package is not supported ........
```

Only last one is install.

I search and didn't found  `SDK v1.7` down load link.I am using `VS2010 ULTIMATE`.Thanks.

Comment: and what OS are you using? Windows Azure SDK requires at least Windows Vista SP1 or newer.

Comment: @astaykov window7 thats all and still ................... any soln :(

Comment: try installing SDK/Tools from [the official Windows Azure Site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/) using the Web Platform Installer link "Install the SDK"

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I shall try this link in off time means tomorrow.Ano  you have any idea how to test it locally ?

Comment: @astaykov I upgrade framework 4.5 and install sdk given through your dll.Now above error is not shown but i get new error about `role`.`Error 103 WAT070 : was not found. Please make sure to build the role project that produces this assembly before building this Windows Azure Cloud Service Project.`.Any idea about this.And thanks for help.